# Beginning C: Behavior Printing Strings

Tags: c

I'm learning C and am currently experimenting with storing strings in variables. I put together the following to try different stuff.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *name = "Tristan";
    char today[] = "January 1st, 2016";
    char newyear[] = {'H','a','p','p','y',' ','N','e','w',' ','Y','e','a','r','!','\n'};
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("My name is %s.\n", name);
    printf("Today is: %s.\n", today);
    printf(newyear);
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this code and running it, I get the following results:

```
Hello world!
My name is Tristan.
Today is: January 1st, 2016.
Happy New Year!
January 1st, 2016
```

Now this is pretty much what I would expect, by why would "January 1st, 2016" get printed out again at the end of the program's output?

If I take the "\n" out of the "newyear" array, it will not do this.

Would someone please explain why this is?

Comment: `newyear` should finish with a `'\0'` instead of the `newline`, to be a C string. Put the `newline` in the `printf` statement, like the others, or, the way you have it, add the `'\0'` *after* the `'\n'`.

Comment: this line: `printf(newyear);` when compiling with all the warnings enabled, will cause the compiler to output a warning: `:9:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]`   Lets' remember that the first argument to `printf()` is a string literal.  I.E. ends with a NUL byte.    so the statement should be: `printf("%16c", newyear);`  Although even better would be: `printf("%15c\n", newyear);`  as that would work correctly on DOS and Windows where the newline sequence is more than one character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newyear` misses a trailing null byte, so `printf`ing it is undefined behavior.
Only string literals implicitly append a null byte. You explicitly initialize every character, so **no null byte is appended**.

Undefined behavior means that something the standard does not define in this occasion will happen. That includes nothing happening, you bursting into tears, or, yes, printing some string twice.

Just add an additional character, i.e., a null byte to the array to resolve the problem:

```
char newyear[] = {'H','a','p','p','y',' ','N','e','w',' ','Y','e','a','r','!','\n', '\0'};
```

---

**Note** that no sane person initializes an automatic `char` array with a string like that. Just stick to string literals! (I think you did it just for learning purposes, though.)

Comment: @Barmar Done. Forgot that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks cad for the great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that strings in C are terminated by the special `'\0'` character.

Not having this terminator at the end of data that is treated as a string will lead to *undefined behavior* as the string functions pass the end of the data searching for the terminator.

Answer (score 0):

This because you are defining `newyear` directly as a `char` array and not through the string literal `""` syntax. This prevents the compiler from adding a trailing `\0` character which is required to mark the end of a string.

Since both `newyear` and `today` reside on stack, in this case they have contiguous storage there so `printf` keeps after the `\n` of `newyear` and prints contents of memory until a `\0` is found.

Answer (score 0):

`newyear` should finish with a `'\0'` instead of the `newline`, to be a C string. You can then put the `newline` in the `printf` statement, like the others:

```
char newyear[] = {'H','a','p','p','y',' ','N','e','w',' ','Y','e','a','r','!','\0'};
//...
printf("%s.\n", newyear);
```

Or, you can add the string terminator to the array, and use the `printf` as you did:

```
char newyear[] = {'H','a','p','p','y',' ','N','e','w',' ','Y','e','a','r','!','\n','\0'};
//...
printf(newyear);
```

In your first two examples, a string defined as `"my string"` automatically has the `'\0'` appended, by the compiler.